# Sort JavaScript array of Objects based on the object's properties in custom way

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I've got an array of objects like this:

```
var arr = [{name:"ew_abb",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_2",type:"p"},{name:"aed_s",type:"b"},{name:"a_s_3",type:"b"},{name:"a_bc",type:"c"},{name:"ew_abc",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_10",type:"p"},{name:"m_s_1",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_3",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_1",type:"p"},{name:"a_bd",type:"c"}];
```

How can I sort it so that all item is ascending order in group and the type=p item always at the top follow by type=b and type=c. Desired result as below:

```
[{name:"m_s_1",type:"p"},{name:"m_s_2",type:"p"},{name:"m_s_10",type:"p"},{name:"a_s_3",type:"b"},{name:"a_bc",type:"c"},{name:"a_bd",type:"c"},{name:"ew_abc",type:"c"},{name:"ew_abb",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_1",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_3",type:"c"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain an array of `order` for sorting and then with an or condition sort on the basis of `name`.

```js
var arr = [{name:"ew_abb",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_2",type:"p"},{name:"aed_s",type:"b"},{name:"a_s_3",type:"b"},{name:"a_bc",type:"c"},{name:"ew_abc",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_10",type:"p"},{name:"m_s_1",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_3",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_1",type:"p"},{name:"a_bd",type:"c"}];

var order = ['p','b','c'];

var result = arr.sort((a,b)=>{
    aa = order.indexOf(a.type);
    bb = order.indexOf(b.type);
    return aa-bb || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator)
If you need case-sensitivity you will have to use RegEx to extract number suffix to compare as numbers.

```js
const arr = [{name:"ew_abb",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_2",type:"p"},{name:"aed_s",type:"b"},{name:"a_s_3",type:"b"},{name:"a_bc",type:"c"},{name:"ew_abc",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_10",type:"p"},{name:"m_s_1",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_3",type:"c"},{name:"m_s_1",type:"p"},{name:"a_bd",type:"c"}]

const coll = new Intl.Collator(undefined,{numeric: true})
const weight = Object.fromEntries(['p','b','c'].map((x,i)=>[x,i])) //map to weights to group

const res = arr.sort(({type:t1,name:n1},{type:t2,name:n2})=>
    weight[t1]-weight[t2] || coll.compare(n1,n2))

console.log(res);
```